# SPFX Tiles webpart

Tags: spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

Hi I am new to SPFX and react JS , i like  to create Tiles webpart from sharepoint list where it will render all properties of tiles from list like icon, colour,text,

I had tried using office fabric ui and tried to create document card, 
I want to add Sharepoint list properties to this document card currently its static value

```
                import * as React from 'react';
                import {
                  DocumentCard,
                  DocumentCardActivity,
                  DocumentCardPreview,
                  DocumentCardTitle,
                  IDocumentCardPreviewProps
                } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DocumentCard';
                import { ImageFit } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Image';
                import { TestImages } from '../../../common/TestImages';

                export class DocumentCardBasicExample extends React.PureComponent {
                  public render(): JSX.Element {
                    const previewProps: IDocumentCardPreviewProps = {
                      previewImages: [
                        {
                          name: 'Revenue stream proposal fiscal year 2016 version02.pptx',
                          linkProps: {
                            href: 'http://bing.com',
                            target: '_blank'
                          },
                          previewImageSrc: TestImages.documentPreview,
                          iconSrc: TestImages.iconPpt,
                          imageFit: ImageFit.cover,
                          width: 318,
                          height: 196
                        }
                      ]
                    };

                    return (
                      <DocumentCard onClickHref="http://bing.com">
                        <DocumentCardPreview {...previewProps} />
                        <DocumentCardTitle
                          title="Large_file_name_with_underscores_used_to_separate_all_of_the_words_and_there_are_so_many_words_it_needs_truncating.pptx"
                          shouldTruncate={true}
                        />
                        <DocumentCardActivity
                          activity="Created a few minutes ago"
                          people={[{ name: 'Annie Lindqvist', profileImageSrc: TestImages.personaFemale }]}
                        />
                      </DocumentCard>
                    );
                  }
                }
```

Comment: There is already a developed [Tiles web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/wp-tiles.md#tiles-web-part) on GitHub if you want to reuse it. or you can change and update it according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you let me check

Comment: Sure, let me know if this is useful and works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kumar,

I don't know if this will help, but I wrote a blog post on the Grid layout -- complete with code samples. It uses the DocumentCard to render the grid items.

Take a look at: https://tahoeninjas.blog/2019/07/28/sharepoint-framework-design-series-layout-patterns-i/

[image: Grid web part]

And if there is something that you're looking for that isn't in the post, let me know and I'll try and update it. That's what the blog post series is all about!

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks Hugo for great article let me give a try and i will let you know

Comment: Thanks Hugo your article worked for me i am able to create responsive card from Sharepoint list

Comment: That's great! Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Thank you sure will let  you know